# Latex makes some characters big

Tags: code

[image]Tried out the package for color coding Python code and when I did, the fonts in the entire document suddenly started acting weird. s, a, o and some other letters are typeset larger than others and the whole text just looks weird. Anyone got any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[procnames]{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{keywords}{RGB}{255,0,90}
\definecolor{comments}{RGB}{0,0,113}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{160,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,150,0}

\lstset{language=Python, 
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
        keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
        commentstyle=\color{comments},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\color{green},
        procnamekeys={def,class}}

\title{Python}
\author{Some guy}

\maketitle

\newpage

\section{Objektorientering}
Såhär skapar man en klass i Py: 

\begin{lstlisting}
class Employee:
    empCount = 0        # kommer shareas av alla instanser

def __init__(self, name, salary):
    self.name = name
    self.salary = salary
    Employee.empcount += 1

def displayEmployee(self):
    print "Name : " self.name, "Salary: ", self.salary
\end{lstlisting}
\lstinline|__init__| är klasskonstruktorn som anropas varje gång man skapar en ny instans.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could remove `\small` from `basicstyle`.

Comment: I don't seem to see the effect mentioned. Can you please post an image showing the result you get and signaling the letter with anomalous size?

Comment: Added. See that the o and m are different sizes for example?

Comment: Weird. This is what I get with your code: http://imgur.com/4YssSkE As you can see, I don't get the variable sized fonts. Could it be a viewer problem?

Comment: This is very likely a viewer problem related to [font hinting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22hinting%22+%22font%22). Could you please try to zoom into 800% at the place where you see the problem, and post a screenshot of that? And please add what TeX distribution version, operating system and PDF viewer do you have.

Comment: Hehe, problem was solved by zooming. Probably should've been the first thing to try :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist No problem. Gald to hear the problem is solved, Perhaps this question will be closed, since it's unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: The issue was a viewer problem.